# Apache POI OPCPackage unable to save Jasper Report generated XLSX

Tags: java, encryption, jasper-reports, apache-poi, xlsx

The overall plan of action is to generate an XLSX file using JasperReports API, then feeding it into Apache POI's encryption code. Example found here: http://www.quicklyjava.com/create-password-protected-excel-using-apache-poi/.

Unfortunately I am unable to encrypt the file when it is generated from Jasper Report, however if I were to create a file inside MS Excel and load it through the code then it encrypts just fine. So the Apache POI library works fine with files coming from Excel.

After debugging I believe I was able to pinpoint the issue.

We use the OPCPackage class to open the file (or in another case load the Input Stream), the class has a method getParts() which sets all the fields. One in particular is packageProperties. It seems that packageProperties is loading the specific Package Part **'application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml'**. However, this part is not found in a Jasper Report generated XLSX file thus remaining null.

```
// Check OPC compliance rule M4.1
if (part.getContentType().equals(ContentTypes.CORE_PROPERTIES_PART)) {
    if (!hasCorePropertiesPart) {hasCorePropertiesPart = true;
```

If this passes, a few lines below we assign this.packageProperties:

```
// Core properties case-- use first CoreProperties part we come across
// and ignore any subsequent ones
if (unmarshallPart instanceof PackagePropertiesPart && needCorePropertiesPart) {
    this.packageProperties = (PackagePropertiesPart) unmarshallPart;
```

The file opens fine, however when I try to save the file the ***saveImpl*** method calls a method called ***addPackagePart*** passing in the 'packageProperties' variable. The class then throws an exception because the field is null. From ***ZipPackage#saveImpl***

```
// If the core properties part does not exist in the part list,
// we save it as well
if (this.getPartsByRelationshipType(PackageRelationshipTypes.CORE_PROPERTIES).size() == 0 && this.getPartsByRelationshipType(PackageRelationshipTypes.CORE_PROPERTIES_ECMA376).size() == 0    ) {
    logger.log(POILogger.DEBUG,"Save core properties part");
        // Add core properties to part list ...
        addPackagePart(this.packageProperties);
```

Here is the exception:

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : part
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1425)
    at com.krfs.web.controller.report.BaseReportController.encryptXlsxOutputStream(BaseReportController.java:717)
    at com.krfs.web.controller.report.BaseReportController.generateJasperReportOutput(BaseReportController.java:547)
    at com.krfs.web.controller.report.BaseReportController.processReportRunningAndGeneration(BaseReportController.java:382)
    at com.krfs.web.controller.report.StandardReportController.processReportRunningAndGeneration(StandardReportController.java:25)
    at com.krfs.web.controller.report.StandardReportController.run(StandardReportController.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.krfs.web.filter.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.krfs.web.filter.XssFilter.doFilter(XssFilter.java:17)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.doFilter(SwitchUserFilter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at com.krfs.web.filter.CustomLoginFilter.doFilter(CustomLoginFilter.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at com.krfs.web.filter.CsrfFilter.doFilter(CsrfFilter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at fr.xebia.servlet.filter.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.krfs.web.filter.SecurityHeadersFilter.doFilter(SecurityHeadersFilter.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.krfs.web.filter.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: part
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.addPackagePart(OPCPackage.java:873)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:448)
    ... 104 more
```

The Jasper Reports code is the standard code to export a XLSX file.

```
JRXlsAbstractExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();

JasperPrint jasperPrint = fillJasperPrint(reportMessenger, reportFile, reportParameters);

exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);                    
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);

exporter.exportReport();
```

This creates the XLSX just fine, however when I extract the contents and look through the package I don't see the properties Part **application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml** which apparently is required by Apache POI to save the file.

The encryption code:

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
        EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs, EncryptionMode.agile);
        Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
        enc.confirmPassword(reportPassword);

        try (OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new ByteArrayInputStream(xlsxOutputStream.toByteArray()))) {
            OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
            opc.save(os);
        }

        fs.writeFilesystem(encryptedOutputStream);
```

Dependency versions:

jasper reports - 4.7.1 (I also tried 6.0.2 with the same result)

apache poi - 3.11

So my question is this, how can I get these two libraries to work in harmony so that I can encrypt the file coming out from jasper reports? Is there a way to inject the output type part core-properties+xml before exporting the file? Is there a way around the Apache POI library to skip finding that part?

I'm hoping someone has seen something similar that they can help me.

Cheers and thank you!

Comment: Have you tried reporting the "can't read/write if no core" as a bug in Apache POI? Have you tried reporting the "you forgot to add a core part" as a bug in Jasper Reports?

Comment: No I havent, I figured its necessary as it is part of the compliance. I may be wrong...

Comment: Clearly both projects have differing ideas of what is and isn't needed for compliance, hence the need to tell both!

Comment: Apache POI can process files missing Core Properties without any issues, see [the last two testcases in this unit test](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/compliance/TestOPCComplianceCoreProperties.java), so I think there must be additional things wrong too with your Jasper File. Do you have a sample small file which shows the problem you can post, along with the code snippet to reproduce it with?

Comment: Thank you for your response! The last two cases do pass with the file I have, however they are missing POIFSFileSystem and the encryption part. It doesn't allow many characters here so I will put the code in the original post. You can find a sample file from the below answer github project ( https://github.com/nestoru/xlsxenc/blob/master/report1.xlsx )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Jasper Reports is writing slightly non-spec-compliant files. Not so far out of support that Excel can't work with them, but non-compliant all the same.

Apache POI can read these files just fine, as shown in [unit tests like this one](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/compliance/TestOPCComplianceCoreProperties.java). Apache POI can save them too, if opened and saved via something like XSSFWorkbook or similar, which triggers the creation of the missing part.

Unfortunately for your use case, you were working down at the OPCPacakge level, and there was a POI bug there. This has been fixed in r1662971, and will be in POI 3.12 beta 2 and later.

For now, you can trigger the core properties creation by changing these lines:

```
OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(inputFilePath, PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
opc.save(os);
```

To instead be:

```
OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(inputFilePath, PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
opc.getProperties();
opc.save(os);
```

Once you're on POI 3.12 beta 2 or later, you won't need that extra call to `getProperties()`.

Also, the code in the github you linked to has some deprecated calls in it, you might want to look at [TestEncryptor.encryptPackageWithoutCoreProperties()](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/TestEncryptor.java) to see how to slightly tweak it to work without deprecated methods.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: stackoverflow does not allow to upload files so you can find the whole project in github: https://github.com/nestoru/xlsxenc

I can confirm this is an error with the apache POI library and not with jasper reports. I am attaching here the relevant files and a temporary work around which involves using libreoffice (so far the best open source excel processing suite, utility and possibly even library). The workaround would involve calling libreoffice as a shell process to "correct" the xlsx coming out of jasper reports in a way POI "understands" it.

Here is how to recreate everything from scratch or part of it given the provided files:

1. From ireport load the attached jrxml file which will output just my logo.
2. Select from ireport the xlsx output type and you will get the report1.xlsx also attached.
3. Now try to encrypt the file using the java program attached and you will get an error as shown below:

   $ javac -cp "*" Enc.java
   $ java -cp ".:*" Enc /home/dev/xlsxenc/report1.xlsx  /tmp/out.xlsx

   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : part     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:503)    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1425)   at Enc.main(Enc.java:34) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: part    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.addPackagePart(OPCPackage.java:873)  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:448)    ... 2 more
4. Now it is time for the workaround. Run the below command to "correct" the xlsx:

   $ libreoffice --headless --convert-to xlsx /home/dev/xlsxenc/report1.xlsx --outdir /tmp

   convert /home/dev/xlsxenc/report1.xlsx -> /tmp/report1.xlsx using Calc Office Open XML
5. And confirm the program now encrypts the file. When you open it it will ask for password. Just type "password" and it will open.

   $ java -cp ".:*" Enc /tmp/report1.xlsx /tmp/out.xlsx

   $ libreoffice  /tmp/out.xlsx

   Xlib:  extension "XINERAMA" missing on display ":10.0".

Comment: libreoffice is adding to the xlsx zip package 'docProps/core.xml' which has the 'part' that POI is looking for **application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml**. Which is why POI works after running the command you added. So I would presume that libreoffice, Excel, and Apache POI are correct.

Comment: If MS Excel parses the file just as  libreoffice does I would say that POI indeed is *failing* to parse the file. The technicalities of why that happens are important for the POI project to catch up and correct the current code. For now you are out of luck with POI for this issue unless you "correct" (should I say "please"?) apache POI while opening and saving the file with libreoffice.